# Samsung monitor flickering or takes long before it powers on after sleep etc

Tags: display, lcd, repair

I have a Samsung BW226 monitor. Recently, after waking computer from sleep, screen flickers and makes hi-freq noise for a few seconds then switch off image, and I have to switch it off and on until it stabilizes. The more the screen gets older the longer it takes it to stabilize.

Is this a physical issue? Is it worth fixing in a lab? Can I fix it myself?

Note: I use 'Blank screen' as the screen saver, then after a while the screen turns off, is it related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully fixed it by following the instructions [here](http://www.overclock.net/t/636236/samsung-226bw-flickers-for-a-few-minutes-when-powering-on#post_12714355).

The specs on my screen however were a bit different, to change all the swollen capacitors I needed the ones listed below. Note that the specs below vary by screen, double check what capacitors you need before you buy them.

- 4 x 820μF 25V 105°
- 1 x 330μF 25V 105°

[Here](http://youtu.be/-mQFROA40nQ) and [here](http://youtu.be/uvzuQ1vxlB4) are two videos explaining the process step by step.

The capacitors' sizes don't matter, however, make sure you don't buy to big a capacitor so they can fit in.
Additionally make sure you insert the capacitors at the right polarity (-/+) on the board.

Here is what a capacitors look like, as you can see they're all labeled with their values.
[image]
[image]

Good luck.